# Cannot access a private repository in gem-fury

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, composer-php, gem-fury

I've setup a private composer repository via gem-fury, but when I'm trying to download one of the packages (using composer-require) I receive the following error:

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The 'https://s3.amazonaws.com:443/gemfury/gems/[SOME_STRING]/[VENDOR][PACKAGE]_[VERSION]_zip?Signature=SIGNATURE&Expires=1481739039&AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS_ACCESS_KEY]' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

P.S.
I know that the authentication worked because composer does receive the package.json file (the latest version is recognized)

Any help would be appretiated

Comment: Is there a proxy in the middle?

Comment: There are no proxies on my end (tried two computers in the office and one remote server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: You may see this issue if you are using `auth.json` to store your Gemfury token. At this time, the only way to work around this issue is to embed the token directly into your repository URL in `composer.json`.

**Long answer**: The reason it doesn't work is due to a bug in Composer CLI. In that particular use-case, when Composer acts on Gemfury's redirect from your private `php.fury.io` repo to a secure S3 download, it includes the `Authorization` header with your Gemfury token. This header conflicts with S3's authentication model, and results in a `400 Bad Request` response.

Resending `Authorization` header on a redirect from one host to another is a fairly significant security concern, and I recommend you reset your Gemfury token and stop using `auth.json` authentication method until this issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks, we ended up switching to another service.

Comment: Is there any intention to solve this issue anytime soon?